# MVC4: List of all urls available on the site?

Tags: reflection, asp.net-mvc-4, selenium, smoke-testing

We have quite a large MVC4 application and we would like to have Selenium go through every page and make sure it loads - some sort of smoke test.

I can use reflection to go through the assembly, find all controllers and all actions, check if actions are not post, come up with parameters for actions that require parameters.
Then I'll feed this list to Selenium and check that everything I need on the pages is done appropriately.

But before I start playing with reflection, I'd like to check if this has already been done, so I don't reinvent the bicycle. I have googled for such thing, but could not find anything.

p.s. Writing the reflection code is not an issue. Selenium is covered as well. Just checking if this has already been done.

Answer (score 1):

The [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) project has a route debugger in place, which does work even if you don't use attribute routing inside your project.

You can see the class that handles displaying the routes [over on Github](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/blob/master/src/AttributeRouting.Web/Logging/LogRoutesHandler.cs) but I'm not sure it will display the routing information when the project isn't run locally. You may need to adapt that code so you can access it safely from your Selenium instance (and make it machine readable using JSON or something).